# Progress bar Autolayout

Tags: ios, progress-bar

I have checked google and here too. 
Does anyone had problem using autolayout in stroyboard with progress bar. 
I am trying to control drag and and no option are popping up. 
those buttons in bottom right of stroyboard. 
also not greyed out. Have anyone encounter this problem? Can anyone help ?

[image]